# (Python 3.4 Tkinter) Button grid filling issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

Trying to figure out how to get a Button in Tkinter to align on X axis (filling the entire axis) to make it stretch as I re-size the window. I know there is a `.pack(fill=X)` command, but I'm using `.grid()` and Python doesn't allow to mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `columnconfigure` method for that:

```
b = tk.Button(root, text="bla")
b.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwes")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```